# Trait 'Crud\Controller\ControllerTrait' not found in Cakephp

Tags: php, azure, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I transferred my cakephp api from linux vps to azure cloud. I configured redirects too but I am getting "Trait 'Crud\Controller\ControllerTrait' not found" error. I checked the bootstrap.php file to check whether its loading crud plugin or not. It does.

Do I need to run composer autoload to load the plugin? If yes then how to in azure as its windows vm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frist, you should check whether the folder named `friendsofcake` exists in `\vendor` directory or not. If not, you need to run the following command to install it by using composer:

```
composer require friendsofcake/crud:^4.3
```

Refer to [this doc](https://crud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that my code base was created using composer version 1.
and to install all packages I had to run

```
composer install
```

However, not all plugins where loaded correctly. If you have composer version 2
installed and facing the issues
kindly  run

```
composer update
```